# How to stop my VPN service in Android?

Tags: android, service, vpn

I've create an application, VPN service, which will block internet packets. Everything is working fine but now I want to stop this VPN service on a button click event so that packets are not blocked anymore.

I've tried to use `stopService(name);` and `stopSelf();`

but nothing happened. What am I doing wrong?

```
public class VpnServiceCls extends VpnService  {
private Thread b;
private ParcelFileDescriptor c;
private PendingIntent a;
Builder builder = new Builder();

private static final String TAG = "VpnService";

@Override
  public void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.d(TAG, "you are in jghbgjyhb");

    if (b != null) {
        Log.d(TAG, "you are in destroy2");
        b.interrupt();
    }

}

public void StopMyVPN()
{
    Log.d(TAG, "you are in jghbgjyhb 898");
    stopSelf();
    if (b != null) {
        Log.d(TAG, "you are in destroy");
        b.interrupt();
    }
    b.stop();
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {


        b= new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try{
                    //here is my logic which is working fine

                }

            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Log.d(TAG, "you are out "+e.toString());
            }

        }
    });//start the service
    b.start();

    return START_STICKY;
}


}
```

on button click i am calling **StopMyVPN()** function but notting happen

Comment: You may want to provide a bit of code that you think is not working as you expect.

Comment: i've update my question. ant suggestions?

Answer (score 5):

you must close and set null interface of vpn .mInterface is vpn interface.

```
public void StopMyVPN() {
    try {
        if (mInterface != null) {
            mInterface.close();
            mInterface = null;
        }
        isRunning = false;
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
    stopSelf();
}
```

you could Bind Activity to your service for calling StopMyVPN.

Answer (score 1):

I also struggled with this issue. At the end I found that my problem was caused by `parcelFileDescriptor` which I was not closing, and that kept my service from destroy.

```
 private fun stop(){

    try {
        parcelFileDescriptor.close()
    } catch (ex: IOException) {
        Log.e(TAG,"parcelFileDescriptor.close()", ex)
    }

    stopForeground(true)
    stopSelf()
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

In a typical android service you can call `stopSelf();` but in this case as it is `VpnService`, same should work only when you closed the interfaces.

So in `VpnService` when you build a Tun by doing `establish()` and get the interface. Now if you want to shutdown your VPN tunnel, then you need to first close this interface and then you need to stop all the threads that you have started, and then you are free to call `stopSelf()` and it should work.